# Autohotkey IniRead pass section name as variable in AHK

Tags: autohotkey, ini

I have the following tiny .ini file:

```
["General"]
"runs"="3"
```

When using this code to read the file, I get a message box stating the correct number of `runs`

```js
path := A_ScriptDir "\setup.ini"
IniRead, temp, % path, "General", "runs"
MsgBox, % temp
```

When I try to pass `General` as a variable, the message box outputs "ERROR"

```js
path := A_ScriptDir "\setup.ini"
iniSection := "General"
IniRead, temp, % path, % iniSection, "runs"
MsgBox, % temp
```

I tried enclosing the variables in `%`-signs, instead of just prefixing them, but it does not make a difference.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Variable names **in an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Expressions)** are not enclosed in percent
> signs. Consequently, **literal strings must be enclosed in double
> quotes** to distinguish them from variables.
>
> To include an actual quote-character inside a literal string, specify
> two consecutive quotes:

```
iniSection := """General"""
```

Comment: Thank very much for pointing that out! I didn't even realize it was interpreting the quotes literally.